# When locus swarm jump does the original still get invected?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been playing with locus swarm and it's pretty neat.

It says it "jumps"

What does it mean by jump?

I saw many enemies get infected by one casts of locust swarms.

So it's not really jump isn't it. It just reinfect?

Answer (score 2):

The many enemies getting infected is the "jumping" part, the locust swarm figuratively "jumps" from one enemy to the next, it means that they can infect other enemies.

Comment: So the original one is keep being screwed. This doesn't happen in haunt right?

Comment: @JimThio Haunt, if I remember correctly, only jumps if the original target dies.